# how to iterate python dict from second item

Tags: python, for-loop

How to start the python iteration from second item directly?

```
d = {
  'name': 'ABC',
  'age': '23',
  'email': 'abc@example.com'  
}
```

I tried by the following code,

```
first_item = next(iter(d))
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

**Expected:**

age : 23 
email : abc@example.com

**Actual:**

name : ABC 
age : 23 
email : abc@example.com

Expecting the solution based on 'Python 3' version.

Thanks,

Comment: how about a check if the key name of the first element of dict is constant ? 
you can simply "continue", if k == "name", inside the for loop. Or is it necessary to skip the first element of dict ?

Comment: Python dicts don't support the element order, so there is no second item. So you yes, skipping the elements by name sounds like a better solution.

Comment: @bereal Python dicts from 3.7 on gurantee insert order ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner wow, indeed. Do dict literals support that, too?

Answer (score 3):

You're not modifying the dictionary, you're building a new iterator and extracting the first (possibly arbitrary item). You shouldn't be relying on the `'name'` being first key anyway for earlier python versions (where dictionaries are not ordered). Instead you can `.pop` the relevant item:

```
>>> d = {
...   'name': 'ABC',
...   'age': '23',
...   'email': 'abc@example.com'  
... }
>>> name = d.pop('name')
>>> name
'ABC'
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     print(k, v)
... 
age 23
email abc@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
items = iter(d.items())
first_item = next(items)
for k, v in items:
    print(k, v)
```

But be careful with Python order dict, better will be skip by key name: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, v in enumerate(d.items()):
    if i == 0:
        pass

    else:
        print({v[0]:v[1]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply **list slicing** to skip the first element.

But first, you will need to convert *d.items()* in a *list* object since it returns a *dict_items* object.

```
for k, v in list(d.items())[1:]: print(k, v)
```

Comment: You should add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the `name` as d in python is not ordered.
If you use `OrderedDict` from collections, you can use d.items()[1:].

Answer (score 0):

It's not a optimal solution but it should work for your requirments.

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
   if(k=="name"):
       continue
   print(k,v)
```